# javascript merge two objects by key name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following two objects:

```
var a = {
  "abc": {
    "111": {
       name: "jon"
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "222": {
       name: "bill"
    }
  }
}

var b = {
  "xyz": {
    "333": {
       name: "mary"
    }
  }
}
```

I then want to create a new object to merge the two by the top level key name. So to get something like this:

```
var c = {
  "abc": {
    "111": {
       name: "jon"
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "222": {
       name: "bill"
    },
    "333": {
       name: "mary"
    }
  }
}
```

I imagine it's probably something you do with `.map()`, `.each()`, or `.reduce()`?
Would jQuery be helpful in this case? if so how?

Comment: Why you think you need jQuery here ?

Comment: @CodeManiac, I actually think it's not needed, but perhaps I am unaware of some jQuery function that would save time. Just wanted to mention it because I use jQuery.

Comment: This can be simply achieved with native JS, if you're using `loadash` then you can expect already built function for such cases, but IMO there's no need of using a complete library where as you can do it just simple loops, If you're already using then it's fine, let me see if there's any such function available in jQuery

Comment: There are two function [`extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and [`merge`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) but none of them can be used directly for such case, you need to loop through the keys and than merge them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),

The main idea is to iterate over both the arrays and maintain a map.

- Iterate over the first object and create a map of all of its properties.
- Than iterate over the second object, and for each of its properties check if it is present in map or not, if it is present than merge the two, If not than simply add it.

```js
var a = { "abc": { "111": { name: "jon" } }, "xyz": { "222": { name: "bill" } } }
var b = { "xyz": { "333": { name: "mary" } } };

let result = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc,[key, value]) => (acc[key] = value,acc),{});
Object.entries(b).reduce((acc,[key, value]) => (acc[key] =acc[key] && Object.assign(acc[key], value)|| value,acc),result);

console.log(result);
```

In case you can use one of your existing objects than a simple solution can be:

```js
var a = { "abc": { "111": { name: "jon" } }, "xyz": { "222": { name: "bill" } } }
var b = { "xyz": { "333": { name: "mary" } } };

Object.entries(a).forEach(([key, value])=>{
  b[key] = Object.assign(b[key] || {}, value);
});

console.log(b);
```

Comment: I'm upvoting since this answers the question and is a clean solution, but it would be great to see some explanation on why this code solves the question (since the code is very reduced, it turns out hard to understand by just reading the code)

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using jQuery or Lodash in your project you can use [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) or [`_.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) respectively. There is no need to reinvent the wheel when you're already using one of those libraries.

```js
var a = { "abc": { "111": { name: "jon" } }, "xyz": { "222": { name: "bill" } } };
var b = { "xyz": { "333": { name: "mary" } } };

console.log($.extend(true, {}, a, b));
console.log(_.merge({}, a, b));
console.log("a =", a);
console.log("b =", b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can only accept one answer, but this answer is also correct and useful.

Comment: @Ben np, upvoting is enough to mark an answer as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

could you use the es6 object destructuring?

```js
var a = {
  "abc": {
    "111": {
       name: "jon"
    }
  },
  "xyz": {
    "222": {
       name: "bill"
    }
  }
}

var b = {
  "xyz": {
    "333": {
       name: "mary"
    }
  }
}

   const c = {abc: a.abc, xyz: [a.xyz, b.xyz]};
    console.log(c);
```